# Counting Search results, and displaying the offset per page

Tags: php, posts, query-posts

I'm trying to achieve the following search result counts while using pagination;

> **Showing 1-9 of 368 Items** - (Page One)
>
> **Showing 9-18 of 368 Items** - (Page Two)

but I'm getting myself turned around with `$count_posts;` I'm not sure I'm fully grasping it. :/

---

**PHP (Search.php)**

```
<?php $post_count = $wp_query->post_count; ?>
<?php $count_products = wp_count_posts( 'products' )->publish; ?>
<?php $count_posts = wp_count_posts()->publish; ?>
```

**HTML/PHP (Search.php)**

```
<p class="small text-uppercase">Showing <?php echo $post_count; . '-' . $post_count; ?> of <strong><?php echo $count_products ?> items</strong></p>
```

My Question: How can I achieve the result I am after?

**EDIT:** 4 JUL 14:56

After quite a bit of testing I was able to figure it out with the help of,  @KrzysiekDróżdż.

```
if ( !is_paged() ) {
    // first page of pagination
    $first_post = absint( $wp_query->get('paged') - 1 );
    $last_post = $first_post + $wp_query->post_count - 1;
    $all_posts = $wp_query->found_posts;
} else {
    $first_post = absint( $wp_query->get('paged') - 1 ) * $wp_query->get('posts_per_page') + 1;
    $last_post = $first_post + $wp_query->post_count - 1;
    $all_posts = $wp_query->found_posts;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you're doing it a little bit wrong...

Here are the problems:

1. `post_count` field contains the number of posts being displayed and not the offset.
2. `wp_count_posts` returns the number of posts globally, not in current query (so it will not be true for queries that have some filters).
3. `echo $post_count; . '-' . $post_count;` is not correct PHP code.

### So how to do this?

All you need is the info from WP_Query:

```
<?php
    $first_post = absint( $wp_query->get('paged') - 1 ) * $wp_query->get('posts_per_page') + 1;
    $last_post = $first_post + $wp_query->post_count;
    $all_posts = $wp_query->found_posts;
?>
<p class="small text-uppercase">Showing <?php echo $first_post . '-' . $last_post; ?> of <strong><?php echo $all_posts; ?> items</strong></p>
```

Comment: I believe `'page'` needs to be `'paged'` in this case.

Comment: Interesting, so as I'm using `<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>` Could I substitute `$wp_query` for `$the_query`? Also I believe there to be a syntax error in `$first_post` somewhere but I can't see it. :/

Comment: @JacobPeattie yep, great catch :)

Comment: @Beaniie You probably shouldn't be using a custom query for search results at all. Is this going in search.php?

Comment: Found the syntax error @KrzysiekDróżdż. You're missing the closing bracket on `absint`.

Comment: @Beaniie there was one redundant opening bracket - writing code on mobile is hard ;)

Comment: @Beaniie are you sure you’re using proper query object everywhere? These numbers don’t make much sense...

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż Thanks again for the assist on this one. :) . +1